# Request получает не весь html

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Мне нужно сделать программу которая будет получать некие данные с сайта https://csgofast.com/#game/double. Все нужные мне данные находятся в теге `<div class="wrapper csgofast"></div>`. Если посмотреть в инспекторе то этот тег спокойно виден, но если посмотреть на исходный код страницы его там нету. `Request.get()` как раз и возвращает этот исходный код. Можете пожалуйста объяснить почему тег не видно в исходном коде? И как тогда можно получить этот тег? Буду рад любому ответу.

Comment: Потому что он добавляется через javascript?

Comment: А в тогда этот тег можно как-то получить?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте скачать вашу страницу при помощи wget или curl например. Скорее всего ваша страница будет идентична полученной из Requests.get(). Возможно что изменяет HTML javascript. Если Это так то нужно использовать как вариант PhantomJS.

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ. Но я уже нашел решение. Использовать модуль selenium